# Global variable environment not read crontab - webmin

Tags: python, cron

In my program, I retrieve a value from a global variable if I run a program in the python console everything works, I defined the global variable as follows:
`export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS = /home/pi/shared/service-account-file.json`

The value is written in:

- /etc/profile
- /home/pi/.profile

However, I want the program to run periodically, using webmin I have added the program to run, but it always ends up loading errors in the global variable:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/shared/CloudRaspberry.py", line 20, in <module>
    db = firestore.Client()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/google/cloud/firestore_v1/client.py", line 110, in __init__
    project=project, credentials=credentials, _http=None
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/google/cloud/client.py", line 226, in __init__
    _ClientProjectMixin.__init__(self, project=project)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/google/cloud/client.py", line 178, in __init__
    project = self._determine_default(project)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/google/cloud/client.py", line 193, in _determine_default
    return _determine_default_project(project)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/google/cloud/_helpers.py", line 186, in _determine_default_project
    _, project = google.auth.default()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/google/auth/_default.py", line 321, in default
    raise exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError(_HELP_MESSAGE)
google.auth.exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError: Could not automatically determine credentials. Please set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS or explicitly create credentials and re-run the application. For more information, please see https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/etc/profile` and `/home/pi/.profile` are only taken into account by interactive shells. I'm pretty sure webmin isn't one, so it will not look there.

The easiest solution would be to specify the variable as a prefix for the command you're running. So, instead of telling webmin to run (for instance)

```
python /home/pi/shared/CloudRaspberry.py
```

you tell it to run

```
GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/home/pi/shared/service-account-file.json python /home/pi/shared/CloudRaspberry.py
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to run bash or sh before python in your crontab to read in the environment variables you want.

Presumably at the moment you have something like

`* * * * * /path/to/script.py > /path/to/script.log 2>&1`

Whereas something like this may help read in the .profile

`* * * * * /bin/bash -c /path/to/script.py > /path/to/script.log 2>&1`

Comment: It's also worth pointing out that, for the sake of defining a couple of variables, there's also the option of adding them to the crontab preamble too: see https://linux.die.net/man/5/crontab.